# Unexpected warnings during loading the module

Tags: npm, webpack

I'm using module from npm with name "jwerty". It works fine, but in the console I have a lot of warnings like below. I'm using webpack@1 and npm@3.

```
WARNING in ./~/jwerty/component.json
Module parse failed: /node_modules/jwerty/component.json Line 2: Unexpected      token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| {
|   "name": "jwerty",
|   "version": "0.3.2",
|     "description": "Awesome handling of keyboard events",
 @ ./~/jwerty ^\.\/.*$

WARNING in ./~/jwerty/jwerty.canBridge.js
Module parse failed: node_modules/jwerty/jwerty.canBridge.js Line 1: Unexpected token function
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| steal('can/control/modifier', './jwerty.js' function(Control){
|
| /**
 @ ./~/jwerty ^\.\/.*$
```

I believed that npm directly makes "entry" point in package.json, so only this file will be loaded when there is no other import or require statements in this "entry" file. I didn't find them, but webpack ouput me with these warnings.

How can I get rid of them and what is the reason I have them?

Comment: Can you try the ´keithamus/jwerty#master´ version? Apparently there are some fixes on the way as discussed at https://github.com/keithamus/jwerty/issues/72 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the `require` inside of files. Library tries to check is there 'jquery', 'zepto' etc, so webpack tries to load and parse files near the `index.js` and raises a warning.